# How to get order data updated by other user

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, sql-update

Order are in table

```
    create table order ( 
      dokumnr int primary key,
      packno char(10)
      );
   insert into order dokumnr values (123);
```

One user sets pack number using

```
update order set packno='Pack1' where dokumnr=123
```

3 seconds later other user retrieves pack number using

```
select packno from order where dokumnr=123
```

However, other user gets null value, not Pack1 as expected. After some time later, correct value Pack1 is returned.

How to get updated data from other user immediately?
3 seconds is long time. It is expected that select returns updated data.

There are lot of transactions running concurrently. Maybe update command is not written to database if second user retrieves it.

How to flush orders table so that current results are returned for second user select ?

Using

PostgreSQL 13.2 and psqlODBC driver.

Comment: That does not happen with PostgreSQL as long as a) both statements are run on the same server and b) the query starts after the update has committed. So you must be using some kind of replication setup, or your transaction management is off.

Comment: Probably query started before update was committed.  How to fix this? How to dedect before select that update is not commited ?

Comment: Should lock placed to order 123 before update and should this lock selected before select? There is delay 3 seconds between select and update when package is created and number retrieved from web service.

Comment: No. A statement is committed as soon as the `COMMIT` statement has returned, then the result is immediately visible to everyone. If you are not using an explicit transaction, the result will be visible as soon as the statement itself finished.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe correct me if I am wrong but I believe *immediately visible to everyone* is not quite true, Wouldn't the DML result still be unavailable to a transaction/statement that started after the dml statement, but before the commit.

Comment: @Belayer Of course; perhaps I was unclear. If the first transaction ends before the second one starts, the second one will see the results of the first. So I'll vote to close this as "not reproducible".

Comment: Question is how to avoid this situation. If update transaction starts select should throw error or wait for update complete. Maybe lock by order id dokumnr should used. This is always reproducible and question should not closed.